# 2d Arrays-lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can ı change this code to make list like [[0],[0,1],[0,1,2]]

```
a=[]
lst = 3
element = 1
for i in range(lst):
    a.append([0,1,2] * element)
print(a)
```

output = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]

Answer (score 2):

You need to build up the content of a little by little.

For example, this would work as follows:

```
a=[]
lst = 3
element = 1
x = []
for i in range(lst):
    x = x + [i]
    a.append(x * element)
print(a)
```

Thus, the value of i is always extended to x and written to a.

Answer (score 1):

The change that works while changing the least amount of code:

```
a.append( [0,1,2][:i+1]* element) # only change this line
```

A better approach would probably be to use a list comprehension. The whole code will then be something like:

```
n = 3
my_list = [0,1,2]
output = [my_list[:i] for i in range(1,n+1)]
print(output)
```

output:

```
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: input —> 3,4

output —> [[0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,3],[0,2,4,6]]

Comment: ım new to python and couldn't do this output

Comment: ım trying to keep the 0 same but +1 the others

Comment: What is the logic behind the desired result? why would an input of `3,4` correspond to that output? 3 will be the number of sublists I think, but what does an input of `4` mean?